# Hibernate delete not working

Tags: hibernate, delete-row

While debugging my server side code, I came to realize that my delete row is not working. I have just copied this code from my insert and replaced session.saveORUpdate to session.delete. Is it the right way to delete a object? What am I doing wrong here ?

I am not getting any exceptions.

```
public void delete(Object dataStore) throws DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError {
    Transaction txD;
    Session session;
    session = currentSession();

    //get first and then fallback to begin.
    if (session.getTransaction() != null
            && session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        txD = session.getTransaction();
    } else {
        txD = session.beginTransaction();
    }

    try {
        session.delete(dataStore);
    } catch (MappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace() ;
    }
    try {
        txD.commit();
        while (!txD.wasCommitted())
            ;
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        log.error("Unable to delete data from "
                + dataStore.getClass().toString());
        txD.rollback();
        throw new DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError(dataStore,
                feedbackManager);
    } catch (TransactionException e) {
        log.debug("txD state isActive" + txD.isActive()
                + " txD is participating" + txD.isParticipating());
        log.debug(e);
        txD.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        txD = null;
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Edit :

I tried putting session.flush after session.delete, did not work.